# call function from parent HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a HTML I have two functions, one is abc with only an alert, another one is to create a new window with window.open() filling with a predefined HTML string. I  want to call the function from parent HTML. I have tried calling parent.abc, and window.parent.abc. Neither of them works.

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myfunction()" type="button">A new Window</button> 
<script>
    var myWindow; 
    function abc() {
        alert("abc");
    };

    function myfunction() {
        var htmlholder = '<!DOCTYPE html>'+
                     '<html>'+
                     '<body>'+
                     '<p>Here is another HTML<\/p>'+
                '<button type="button1" onclick="parent.abc()">Call parentabc<\/button>'+
                     '<\/body>'+
                     '<\/html>';

        myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
        myWindow.document.write(htmlholder);

    };

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pop-ups/tabs have `opener`, frames have `parent`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use opener instead of parent. Have added fiddler.

```
   function myfunction() {
        var htmlholder = '<!DOCTYPE html>'+
                     '<html>'+
                     '<body>'+
                     '<p>Here is another HTML<\/p>'+
                '<button type="button1" onclick="opener.abc()">Call parentabc<\/button>'+
                     '<\/body>'+
                     '<\/html>';

        myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
        myWindow.document.write(htmlholder);

    };
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/0txe2qvx/